# VBA compiler error expected :=

Tags: ms-access, vba

Any one help me. What is a wrong. Compiler need =

```vb
Private Function Test(id as integer, first as boolean) 
    ' this is the function code  
end function

Private Command_Btn_Click()
  dim rs as dao.recordset 
  dim qry as string 
  qry = "SELECT ID, First_login From Users Order by ID"
  set rs = currentdb.openrecordset(qry) 
  if rs.recordcount = 0 then
    msgbox "No record "
    exit sub
  else 
    rs.movefirst
    do while not rs.eof
      test(rs.fields(0),rs.fields(1)) ' This is compiler error := 
      rs.movenext
    loop
  end if
  rs.close
end sub
```

I try this 
1:  `Private (Or public) test(byval Id as integer, byval First as boolean)` 
2: `Private (or public) test(byval Id as integer, byval First as boolean) as variant()`

I don't know what's wrong but I think this error is a very trivial :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you put `<br>` in your code? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Anyway, you need

```
Call test(rs.fields(0), rs.fields(1))
```

or

```
test rs.fields(0), rs.fields(1)
```